# how to pass a value to rails model method without submit form?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a class in my model like the following:

```
class Project::Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :cancel_id
  def save_loc_values
    update_record = Project::Loc.find_by_Project_Reference(project.Project_Reference)
    update_record.update_attributes({
      Status: 'D',
      Cancellation_Date: DateTime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T.%L"),
      CancellationReason_id: self.cancel_id
    })
  end
end
```

In my `form`, am using the `attr_accessor` field

```
<%= form_for @area, remote: true, html: {data: {save_warning_form: true}} do |f| %>
  <%= form_error(f) %>
  <%= f.text_field :cancel_id %>
  <%= link_to 'omit', save_loc_values_project_areas_path(area_id: @area.id, cancel_id: @area.cancel_id), remote: true, method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

I created a route and for my custom method in my `controller` like the following,

```
def save_loc_values
  @area = Project::Area.find(params[:area_id])
  @return = @area.save_loc_values
end
```

The problem in It is working fine and saving the values of `Status` and `Cancellation_Date` into the another database table. But the On change cancel_id value is not saving. How can I pass and save the onchange `cancel_id`?

Thanks and I really would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure `params[:area_id]` is not empty??? I see you don't send it from gui.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. Please have a look and `params[:area_id]` is not empty. It has value. But not `cancel_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**html**:

```
 <%= link_to_function "ommit", "ommit('#{@ommit.id}')" %>
```

**js**:

```
function ommit(id)
{
  $.ajax({
    url:"/your_controller_name/save_loc_values",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "ommit_id=" + id + "&cancel_id=" + $('#cancel_id').val(),
    type: 'GET/POST'# your method type
  });
}
```

**controller**:

```
def save_loc_values
  @area = Project::Area.find(params[:area_id])
  @return = @area.save_loc_values(params[:cancel_id])
end
```

**Model**:

```
def save_loc_values(cancel_id)
    update_record = Project::Loc.find_by_Project_Reference(project.Project_Reference)
    update_record.update_attributes({
      Status: 'D',
      Cancellation_Date: DateTime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T.%L"),
      CancellationReason_id: cancel_id
    })
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is : You are not using the `cancel_id` which you are setting in the `view`.

Just pass the `cancel_id` which is coming in `params` to `save_loc_values` action like `@return = @area.save_loc_values(params[:cancel_id])` and use the same with `update_attributes`

#### Update :

```
<%= form_for @area, url: save_loc_values_project_areas_path, method: :post  remote: true, html: {data: {save_warning_form: true}} do |f| %>
  <%= form_error(f) %>
  <%= f.text_field :cancel_id %>
  <%= f.submit 'omit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit, I am confused and would you explain in detail or show an example please.

Comment: Hi, I tried `<%= link_to 'omit', save_loc_values_project_areas_path(cancellation_id: @area.cancel_id), remote: true, method: :post %>` and its not passing the current value to the controller.

Comment: What all params are you receiving in the action of your controller? Is cancel_id present in params ?

Comment: Can you please try this line `<%= link_to 'omit', save_loc_values_project_areas_path(@area.cancel_id), remote: true, method: :post %>`

Comment: Amit, I tried the above what you said and `@area.cancel_id` is not passing through. I did like the following and I got the `area_id` but not `cancel_id`. `<%= link_to 'omit', save_loc_values_project_areas_path(area_id: @area.id, cancel_id: @area.cancel_id), remote: true, method: :post %>`

Comment: Just want to confirm 1 thing, Are you trying to pass the `cancel_id` which is being set in the view by user through `<%= f.text_field :cancel_id %>` or its an attribute of `@area` object ?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the cancel_id which is being set in the view by the user and getting the value in model method.

Comment: Can u plz update your question with the content of your whole form which is in the view ..

Comment: Hi, I got it working by adding bit of javascript. I added the Current cancel_id value to the href in javascript and got it working. But Please tell me is that a good way to do that.

Comment: So, actually there are 2 ways to do it 1) Setting the proper name for the attribute in the form so that if gets submitted along with the form and 2) Is through JS which you have already done. I can show you how to do it without extra JS if you post the content of the form you have written in the view.

Comment: Hi amit, I added the content of the form, have a look. Thanks

Comment: Please try my updated answer and just check params (cancel_id should be present) and let me know if you face any errors?