# How to pass value from input type in html to a controller in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am beginner in html and ruby on rails. It sounds a very basic question but after many attempts I am not getting it how to pass value from a input type which is not in a form to a controller.

This is my code -

```
<div style = "border:1px solid black; padding:1em;">
    <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.id) %>
    <br><br>

    Price : <%= product.price %>

    Quantity : <input type="text" name='quantity' value = '1' min ='1'/>
    <br><br>

    <% if session[:cart_id] && @cart_item_ids.include?(product.id) %>
    <button><%= link_to 'Remove', remove_item_path(:product_id => product.id)
    %></button>
    <% elsif session[:cart_id] %> 
    <button><%= link_to 'Add To Cart', add_to_cart_path(:product_id => product.id, :price => product.price, :quantity => 'quantity')
    %></button>
    <% end%>
  <br>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def add_to_cart
    byebug
    cart_item = CartItem.new
    cart_item.product_id = params[:product_id]
    cart_item.quantity = 1
    cart_item.price = params[:price]
    cart_item.cart_id = session[:cart_id]
    cart_item.save

    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    category = Category.find(product.category_id)

    redirect_to category_path(:id => product.category_id)
  end

  def remove_item
    CartItem.where(:cart_id =>  session[:cart_id]).where(:product_id => params[:product_id]).first.destroy
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    redirect_to category_path(:id => product.category_id)
  end

  def view_cart
    cart = Cart.where(:consumer_id => session[:consumer_id]).first
    @cart_items = CartItem.where(:cart_id => cart.id)
    render 'show'
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the controller code, please?

Comment: I had added controller's code.

Comment: Go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560881/how-to-pass-a-value-to-rails-model-method-without-submit-form

Comment: The question is using a form_for  but i am not using any form

Comment: The question is: __why__ are you not using any form? That's exactly what they're for, posting data to server.

Comment: Actually I am a bit confused. It is an add to cart functionality and initially i had to show just items, so i was displaying the items using get request but now i have to take quantity as input. And also form can be submitted in two ways, either user can add an item to his cart or he can remove an added item, which is a bit complicated using forms (and i am a beginner).  I thought what i was trying to do is very basic.

Comment: Its seems than i have to go for forms.

Comment: @Shubh they do without any form, they use the link, you have to use some methods like `onChagne` method of input type. look at the answer carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use a `form` to post the data, or you need to use some asynchronous Javascript request to post the data.